# JQuery .serialize sends default values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I am using ajax with JQuery to serialize my forms and send the data to my insert.php page so it inserts into my DB.

I am removing any inputs that are empty in the form form.serialize.  This is to make sure those values are inserted as NULL into my DB.

I have to set a default value of nothing for each input, I'm assuming, to make this process work.

However, when I do that, I find that when the form is serialized, those inputs that are set to an empty default value are NOT sent.  Seems like .serialize sends the input's default values, not what the user types into the inputs.

How can I work around this?

Here's how I'm setting up an input in my form that has a blank default value:

```
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label">Item Price</label>
                <div class="input-icon right">
                    <i class="fa"></i>
                    <input type="text" id="item_price" name="item_price" class="currency_mask form-control" value="">
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Here's how I omit empty values from .serialize in my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax_insert.php?table=invoice_item",
     type: "post",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: $("#item_form :input[value!='']").serialize(), //remove blank inputs so they aren't passed into the db and are inserted as NULL
     success: ....
```

No matter what is typed/entered into the Item Price field, the default value is used from the form.  Because the default value is nothing, it is omitted from .serialize.

I definitely need to omit blank inputs from being serialized so that field is set to NULL in my DB.   So that's why I omit them before the form is serialized.

Comment: I think that should be `$(this).serialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your partial question, created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dxq1qstt/) for you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#item_form').on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
            return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
        }).serialize());
    });
});
```

Replace alert with the data variable like this:

```
var data = $(this).find(":input").filter(function () {
                return $.trim(this.value).length > 0
            }).serialize();
```

and hence your AJAX will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax_insert.php?table=invoice_item",
     type: "post",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: data
     success: ....
```

Comment: Thank you!  That makes sense. It works well for my purposes.